# What's the meaning of "you need to grn"?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

Recently I received this email from a client with reference to a purchase order:

> If you have received I will have to reinstate the lines on the po and then you need to grn.

I can't figure out what the meaning could be.

Comment: GRN could stand for "Goods Received Notice" and the client could have meant "You need to send the GRN". In any case, this seems like a poorly constructed sentence.

Comment: The fact that you understand "po" should reveal to you that abbreviations are being used, further compounded by the fact "grn" cannot possibly be a word (it lacks vowels). This can be solved by googling "grn".

Comment: The immediate reading would be _go right now_, but that makes no sense in the context you’ve given. A verb seems called for, but there [do not seem to be any verbal phrases commonly abbreviated GRN](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/GRN). As such, this becomes a game of speculative guesswork, aiming at an abbreviation which may or may not exist, and may or may not be limited to a very narrow user base, which makes the question too narrow in scope and off-topic here.

Comment: You need to provide more context.

Answer (score 1):

GRN means [Goods Received Note](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/goods-received-note) (sometimes called Goods Receipt Note). The goods receipt note is an internal document. This record is used to confirm all goods have been received and often compared to a purchase order before payment is issued.

The client wants you to *send* a GRN which will describe each item and the quantity of each item received.

The client can use it to raise any issues, update their stock records or use it to match against the original purchase order and supplier invoice.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the phrase "grn" as a whole, but perhaps the "rn" portion stands for "reference number?"

Comment: Maybe, the exact sentence is "If you have received I will have to reinstate the lines on the po and then you need to grn"

Comment: Hello, ruble. Wildly speculative answers are considered inappropriate on ELU.